# How to give more ram to virtualbox on Ubuntu than what its limited?

Tags: virtualbox

I have 16GB of ram on my Mac OS X and I'm running Virtualbox and I want to know how if I want to give more than 4GB of ram that it's limited like say I want to give 8 or more of my available ram?

Will it be possible to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer [yes](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/3069).